# jquery: find out at which position (order) a particular element is among its neighbors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think this should be simple but I haven't been able to figure it out:

I have a container with a couple of children:

```
<div id='container'>
  <div id='one'>some</div>
  <div id='two'>random</div>
  <div id='three'>text</div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to know the position of say element $('#two')... which should return 2 (as the element is the second of the container's children, $('#one').... should return 1 and so on.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Martin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) for this:

```
$('#two').index() // 1
```

Note that the index is zero-based.